# How to add element to a list attribute in DDB using DynamoDBMapper?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table which looks like:

```
primaryKey: primaryKeyValue
secondaryKey: secondaryKeyValue
key3 : ["abc", "cde", "fgh"]
```

Currently the following is how I am updating the db:

```
private DynamoDBMapperConfig saveConfig = DynamoDBMapperConfig.builder().withSaveBehavior(DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES).build()


public void createOrUpdateTest(ExternalTestMetadata testMetadata) {
        log.info("Saving test metadata {} into DDB.", testMetadata);
        try {
            dynamoDBMapper.save(testMetadata, saveConfig);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String errorMessage = String.format("Failed to save test metadata into DDB, testId: {%s}. Reason: %s",
                testMetadata.getTestId(), e.getMessage());
            log.error(errorMessage, e);
            throw new DependencyException(errorMessage, e);
        }
    }
```

```
TableName.TableNameBuilder tableNameBuilder = TableName.builder().primaryKey(primaryKeyValue).secondaryKey(secondaryKeyValue);

tableNameMapper.createOrUpdateTest(tableNameBuilder.build());
```

How do I add a string to the third key? If it does not exist I need it to be added to a list ([first element]), if it does exist, it needs to be appended to the list.

Do I have to use "APPEND_SET"?? Please help, thank you

Answer (score -1):

You are using the mapper, which maps server side items to client side objects. If you want to append to a list, read the item into local memory, append locally and save the item.

If you don't want to read, then use a lower level client.

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean by lower level client?

Comment: Low level client is the default client which provides you full control of the API. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.SDKOverview.html

Answer (score -1):

Just had to use APPEND_SET and follow this guide shown here: APPEND_SET

Follow this guide for more details: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-the-savebehavior-configuration-for-the-dynamodbmapper/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).